# Find combinations of elements of size bigger than the number of elements

Tags: prolog, combinations, permutation, list

For example, I have a safe that needs an answer of length 5 (XXXXX) numbers but you only use 1,2,3. So some combos could be 1,2,3 & 1,1,1 & 1,1,2 etc... but I need to find all possibilities.

I have brainstormed and I think I need to find all permutations of all combos of the three numbers but I can't figure out how to find the answer in size 5.

If it was just three numbers and the answer was length 3 I could just use the permutation function but this doesn't work since I need it to be a larger size than elements used.

Comment: Before building a number, can you build a list of lenght 5 with the same conditions

Answer (score 2):

No problemo with [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- length(Zs, 5), Zs ins 1..3, labeling([], Zs).
   Zs = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
;  Zs = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
;  Zs = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3]
;  Zs = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
;  Zs = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
;  Zs = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
;  Zs = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1]
;  Zs = [1, 1, 1, 3, 2]
;  Zs = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
;  Zs = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

No problemo, use [prolog-lists](/questions/tagged/prolog-lists):

```
rebmem(L,Y) :- member(Y,L).

?- length(Zs,5), maplist(rebmem([1,2,3]),Zs).
Zs = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
Zs = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2] ;
Zs = [1, 1, 1, 1, 3] ;
Zs = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1] ;
Zs = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2] ;
Zs = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3] ;
Zs = [1, 1, 1, 3, 1] ;
Zs = [1, 1, 1, 3, 2] ;
Zs = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3] ;
Zs = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
```